# User must log in upon each app refresh after upgrading the Firebase JavaScript SDK and Expo SDK 44 | Expo Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I recently upgraded to Expo SDK 44 as well as Firebase JavaScript SDK 9.6.10.

I am using Firebase compat in my Firebase configuration.

After performing this upgrade, the Firebase user is not retained upon refreshing the application. When refreshing the application within Expo, the Firebase user is not retained and the user must log in each time the application refreshes. This issue also exists in native builds.

My configuration is as follows:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/functions";

import {
  API_KEY,
  AUTH_DOMAIN,
  PROJECT_ID,
  STORAGE_BUCKET,
  MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  APP_ID,
  MEASUREMENT_ID
} from "@env";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: APP_ID,
  measurementId: MEASUREMENT_ID
};


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export { firebase };
```

```js
const onLoginPress = () => {
  if (!email) {
    alert("Enter a valid email address");
    return;
  };
  if (!password) {
    alert("Enter Password");
    return;
  };
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((response) => {
      const uid = response.user.uid
      const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
      usersRef
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
        .then(firestoreDocument => {
          if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
            alert("User does not exist anymore.")
            return;
          }
          const user = firestoreDocument.data();
          user.id = firestoreDocument.id
          return navigation;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          alert(error)
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert(error)
    })
}
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(User => {
    if (User) {
      usersRef
        .doc(User.uid)
        .get()
        .then((document) => {
          const userData = document.data()
          setUser(userData)
          userGlobal = User.uid;
          if (!(Platform.OS === 'web')) {
            registerForPushNotificationsAsync(User.uid).then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));
            registerBackgroundFetchAsync().then((result) => {
              console.log(result)
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error registering background task service: ", error)
            });
            registerBackgroundNotificationsAsync().then((result) => {
              console.log(result)
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error registering background notifications service: ", error)
            })
            notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
              Analytics.logEvent('notificationReceived');
              Notifications.getBadgeCountAsync().then(result => {
                Notifications.setBadgeCountAsync(result + 1)
              })
            });

            responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
              Notifications.getBadgeCountAsync().then(result => {
                Notifications.setBadgeCountAsync(result - 1)
              });
            });

            return () => {
              Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
              Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
            };
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          setLoading(false)
        })
    } else {
      setAuthenticated(false);
      setUser(null);
      userGlobal = null;
      setAccount(null);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi, after `setUser(userData)` how are you able to access the user in other components?

Answer (score 0):

Async storage was extracted from react-native core in react native version 0.64.3
Refactoring firebase 9.6.10 to use modular imports (v9) vs using compat (v8) namespace resolved this issue.

[image: Expo Warning - React Native Async Storage]